# Thread safety while access Db in spring bean

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, thread-safety, double-checked-locking

I have a singleton spring service that is being called by spring rest controller.

The singleton service `MyService` has some method `addRecordIfNotExistsBefore`, which has the following implementation:

```
public void addRecordIfNotExistsBefore(String record){

    boolean isExist = checkIfRecordNotExitsBefore();

    if (!isExist){
        addRecordToDb(record);
    }
}
```

The problem is - as appears - when two clients request the same service at the same time, then the record being added twice to the database.

I can apply the [double-check idiom](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Double-checked_locking) in some simple implementation like:

```
public void addRecordIfNotExistsBefore(String record){

    boolean isExist = checkIfRecordNotExitsBefore();

    if (!isExist){
        synchoronized(this){

            isExist = checkIfRecordNotExitsBefore();
            if (!isExist){
                addRecordToDb(record);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does it valid solution, or is there another better solution?

Comment: That is why there are different database propagation levels. Try `SERIALIZABLE` and then with your initial implementation. Also if you really want to fix it I would suggest adding a unique constraint somewhere as if it is the same record and it is only allowed once you should also have a unique constraint somewhere.

Comment: I tried @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) on the service method but still not work!

Comment: Are your transactions working?

Answer (score 2):

I think the only solution is to have database constraint to check uniqueness of record in database scene  your application is deployed in multiable nodes